# how to accept a char * in C using scanf()

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to input a word in the form of a char * in C

Such as :

```
char *inputText;
scanf("%s",inputText);
printf("This is your string %s",inputText);
```

I have tried with using

```
scanf("%s",&inputText);
```

As well
Each time I either get a compile error or Segmentation fault when I run it

```
"format '%s' expects type 'char *' but argument 2 has type 'char **'
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something really simple but It's quite confusing.
My code depends on using char * 
If theres a way to convert an easier input method into char * then can you show me that method?

Comment: You can't scan into empty space. Allocate some space for the `inputText` or use a preallocated array.

Comment: When scanning a string, you don't need to pass the address of a `char *`... just the `char *` itself.  You also need to make sure the pointer points at something (`malloc` space, or use an array, etc.).  Also, you should always specify the width so `scanf` won't try to read a string longer than you have space for.

Comment: @zenith I like this question better, as it's way more to the point. That linked one is "OMGHORRIBLEBLOCKOFCODE".

Comment: @MicroVirus True, there are probably better duplicates out there.

Comment: [Please don't use `scanf`](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: @jamesdlin That page's recommendation is to first scan an entire line and then use `sscanf`, which is no different than `scanf`.

Comment: @MicroVirus Recovering from invalid input, and in general having logical line-oriented input, is far easier if you read a whole line at a time and then try to parse it.

Comment: @MicroVirus It's no different for `scanf` for *this particular problem*.  That doesn't mean that `scanf` is advisable to use in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized `inputText` so it's pointing to some random memory which you probably don't even own. Asking `scanf` write to that memory location results in undefined behavior.

You need to allocate memory for the pointer to point to:

```
char *inputText = malloc(amount_of_bytes_to_allocate);
```

Now `inputText` points to the allocated memory, and `scanf` can happily write to that memory location without a segfault. Remember that you must `free(inputText)` when you're done using the allocated memory.

But preferably, you wouldn't use dynamic memory (`malloc`) in this case since you can do just fine with automatic memory: just declare `inputText` as an *array* instead of a pointer:

```
char inputText[size_of_array];
```

Remember that your `size_of_array` (or `amount_of_bytes_to_allocate`) must be large enough to hold the entire string that `scanf` is going to write into the array, *including* the terminating null character. Otherwise you'll have undefined behavior again.

Comment: Would you suggest I go with getline() if I cannot predict the size of the incoming word/string?

Comment: Maybe, but remember that it's a non-standard function.

Answer (score 0):

First, as a general precaution, it's a good idea to initialize new pointers to `NULL` so as to ensure they aren't pointing to memory that your program isn't allowed to access.

I would use `getline()` as an alternative to `scanf()` especially if the size of your input can vary. It allocates a properly-sized buffer for you, so you don't need to worry about entering too many characters.

```
char *inputText = NULL;
int inputSize;

if (getline(&inputText, &inputSize, stdin) >= 0)
   printf("This is your string: %s\n", inputText);
else
   printf("Error\n");
```

You still need to free the memory allocated to `inputText` yourself, so don't forget to do that and set it to `NULL` once you're done with it.

Comment: Just wanted to know; how does &inputSize work in that case? Does it just allocate memory for the char * after it checks the size of the input or does it have some extremely hard to reach limit?

Comment: That parameter is a pointer to an `int` which is used to store the size of the string read by the function. So it basically just counts the number of characters and updates `inputSize` to that number.